# Apache ImportError: no module named request (urllib.request)

Tags: python, apache, ubuntu, flask, python-requests

When i start flask app without apache server i don't have any problems, but when in apache he log's that no module named request. Tried to find solve in stack-overflow, but nothing helps.
Ubuntu 16.04

Apache site config:

```
<VirtualHost *>
        ServerName s4lat.me 

        WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/flask/headlines/headlines.wsgi
        WSGIDaemonProcess headlines python-path=/var/www/flask/headline:/var/www/flask/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages
        <Directory /var/www/flask/headlines>
                WSGIProcessGroup headlines
                WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
                AllowOverride all
                Require all granted
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Apache2server error log:

```
[Wed Jul 11 12:26:29.301337 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 17014] [remote 188.19.172.55:22332] mod_wsgi (pid=17014): Target WSGI script '/var/www/flask/headlines/headlines.wsgi' cannot be loaded as Python module.
[Wed Jul 11 12:26:29.301373 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 17014] [remote 188.19.172.55:22332] mod_wsgi (pid=17014): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/var/www/flask/headlines/headlines.wsgi'.
[Wed Jul 11 12:26:29.301402 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 17014] [remote 188.19.172.55:22332] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Wed Jul 11 12:26:29.301427 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 17014] [remote 188.19.172.55:22332]   File "/var/www/flask/headlines/headlines.wsgi", line 3, in <module>
[Wed Jul 11 12:26:29.301470 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 17014] [remote 188.19.172.55:22332]     from headlines import app as application
[Wed Jul 11 12:26:29.301481 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 17014] [remote 188.19.172.55:22332]   File "/var/www/flask/headlines/headlines.py", line 3, in <module>
[Wed Jul 11 12:26:29.301493 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 17014] [remote 188.19.172.55:22332]     import feedparser
[Wed Jul 11 12:26:29.301499 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 17014] [remote 188.19.172.55:22332]   File "/var/www/flask/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/feedparser.py", line 142, in <module>
[Wed Jul 11 12:26:29.301510 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 17014] [remote 188.19.172.55:22332]     import urllib.request, urllib.parse, urllib.error
[Wed Jul 11 12:26:29.301526 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 17014] [remote 188.19.172.55:22332] ImportError: No module named request
```

python(env) packages:

(env) root@mysql-s-1vcpu-1gb-lon1-01:/var/www/flask# python -m pip freeze

```
certifi==2018.4.16
chardet==3.0.4
click==6.7
feedparser==5.2.1
Flask==1.0.2
get==1.0.3
idna==2.7
itsdangerous==0.24
Jinja2==2.10
MarkupSafe==1.0
post==1.0.2
public==1.0.3
query-string==1.0.2
request==1.0.2
requests==2.19.1
urllib3==1.23
Werkzeug==0.14.1
```

Comment: Are you using python 3? In that case, what is the output of `python3 -m pip freeze`?

Comment: Your mod_wsgi is likely compiled for Python 2.7, not Python 3.6. It must be compiled for the version of Python you want to use. See http://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/user-guides/virtual-environments.html

Comment: Ok, I'll try now